# Setting custom font to bold

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have successfully added a custom font to my project and it works just fine by doing this line of code amongst other things:

```
 [sideScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Caveman" size:34]];
```

However I want this custom font to be bolded. I have researched this and everyone seems to be saying to add "-Bold" at the end of the font name or "-BoldMT" making it appear like the following:

```
 [sideScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Caveman-Bold" size:34]];
```

When I run my project it does not seem to work. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Perhaps the font I am using does not work with Bolding?

Thank you!

Comment: A lot of times, specialty fonts actually have a separate font called **name**-Bold. A quick google search of the Caveman font reveals that may be true here to. Custom fonts aren't necessarily like standard fonts (Times New Roman for instance), where bold is an option to apply to it. You'd need to actually add the Caveman-Bold font as you added the Caveman font.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have successfully added a custom font to my project and it works just fine by doing this line of code amongst other things:

Dude you added a **CUSTOM FONT** to your iOS bundle.

If you want a bold version of that font you need to provide one the system wont do it for you.

Comment: how to generate bold ttf file?

Answer (score 7):

You are on the right track when you mention the font not being able to be bolded.  You can verify this with this bit of code that will encho out to console all available fonts, then you can look for your font in there.

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
  NSArray *fontNames;
  NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
  for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
  {
      NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
      fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
          [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
          [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
      for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
      {
          NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
      }
      [fontNames release];
  }
  [familyNames release];
```

Comment: Thank you. It does not appear to be in the list of fonts. However, when I click on the .TTF file on my Mac, it shows me two sets of the alphabet, one in bold and one in normal. Does this still mean it cannot be done? Thanks

Comment: I wanted to add arial fonts with regular and bold but was not working.But with your code i checked name and it as ArialMT rather than Arial and Arial-BoldMT rather than Arial-Bold. This helped..

Comment: These names shown are not the required. You should use the PostScript names, which may be different than the font names shown by this script

Comment: Great Answer, I can see my actual added font names and can use in 'FontWithName' method accurately.

Comment: It's also easy to do this "manually" by `NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont familyNames]);` and then `NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"SomeFont"]);` on the family you wanna get available font names of.

Answer (score 4):

1. Find in `Spotlight` "Font Book"
2. Open it and find your font in the list of fonts
3. As you can see, any font has several names. In your code you always should use `PostScript` name of your font. Sometimes `PostScript` name is not similar with file name of your font.

Comment: The only thing that works 100% with custom font family including variations, thanks.